# Django Class Based Views Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.) - webhook

Tags: django

I have made a class based view to act a webhook but whenever a request comes in I get `Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /gc_callback/`
I do have the csrf_exempt decorator for dispatch but it seems it does nothing

```
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Webhook, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any suggestions?

-Edit-
It seems that you need to include the csrf_exempt in the urls.

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding , @csrf_exempt decoarator

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook(request):
    # Do some stuffs...

    # Return an HTTPResponse as Django expects a response from the view
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```